# Real-time executive approach, can be run in desktop Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, virtualization, real-time

With the real-time executive approach, a small real-time kernel coexists with the Linux kernel. This real-time core uses a simple real-time executive that runs the non-real-time Linux kernel as its lowest priority task and routes interrupts to the Linux kernel through a virtual interrupt layer.

All interrupts are initially handled by the core and are passed to standard Linux only when there are no real-time tasks to run. Real-time applications are loaded in kernel space and receive interrupts immediately, giving near hardware speeds for interrupt processing.

I wonder how to test this in ordinary desktop Linux, e.g. Ubuntu? If it's even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very much like the approach taken by [RTLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTLinux), which still seems to be available but not commercially supported.

That being said, there's [a community unto itself](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) about real-time Linux concepts, and [the CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT patch](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_Patch) would seem to enable the functionality you're looking for. As with all kernel hacking, do so at your own risk. There's a [HOWTO](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO) available to help you get started.